# pyspark: Filter one RDD based on certain columns of another RDD

Tags: python, apache-spark, mapreduce, pyspark

I have two files in a spark cluster, `foo.csv` and `bar.csv`, both with 4 columns and the same exact fields: 
`time, user, url, category`.

I'd like to filter out the `foo.csv`, by certain columns of `bar.csv`.  In the end, I want key/value pairs of (user, category): [list, of, urls].  For example:

```
foo.csv:
11:50:00, 111, www.google.com, search
11:50:00, 222, www.espn.com, news
11:50:00, 333, www.reddit.com, news
11:50:00, 444, www.amazon.com, store
11:50:00, 111, www.bing.com, search
11:50:00, 222, www.cnn.com, news
11:50:00, 333, www.aol.com, news
11:50:00, 444, www.jet.com, store
11:50:00, 111, www.yahoo.com, search
11:50:00, 222, www.bbc.com, news
11:50:00, 333, www.nytimes.com, news
11:50:00, 444, www.macys.com, store

bar.csv:
11:50:00, 222, www.bbc.com, news
11:50:00, 444, www.yahoo.com, store
```

Should result in:

```
{
(111, search):[www.google.com, www.bing.com, www.yahoo.com],
(333, news): [www.reddit.com, www.aol.com, www.nytimes.com]
}
```

In other words, if a (user, category) pair exist in `bar.csv`, I'd like to filter out **all** lines in `foo.csv` if they have that same exact (user, category) pair.  Thus in the above example, I'd like to remove all lines in `foo.csv` with `(222, news)` and `(444, store)`.  Ultimately, after I remove the lines I want, I'd like a dictionary with key/value pairs like: `(user, category): [list, of, urls]`.

Here's my code:

```
fooRdd = sc.textFile("file:///foo.txt/")
barRdd = sc.textFile("file:///bar.txt/")


parseFooRdd= fooRdd.map(lambda line: line.split(", "))
parseBarRdd = barRdd.map(lambda line: line.split(", "))



# (n[1] = user_id, n[3] = category_id) --> [n[2] = url]
fooGroupRdd = parseFooRdd.map(lambda n: ((n[1], n[3]), n[2])).groupByKey().map(lambda x: {x[0]: list(x[1])})
barGroupRdd = parseBarRdd.map(lambda n: ((n[1], n[3]), n[2])).groupByKey().map(lambda x: {x[0]: list(x[1])})
```

The above code works and gets the datasets in the format I want:

```
(user_id, category): [all, urls, visited, by, user, in, that, category]
```

However, couple issues: 1) I think it returns a list of dictionaries w/ just one k/v pair and 2) I'm stuck on what to do next.  I know what to do in english: get the keys in `barGroupRdd` (tuples), and remove all lines in fooGroupRdd that have the same key.  But I'm new to pyspark and I feel like there are commands I'm not taking advantage of.  I think my code can be optimized.  For example, I don't think I would need to create that `barGroupRdd` line because all I need from `bar.csv` is (user_id, category) -- I don't need to create a dictionary.  I also think I should filter out first, and *then* create the dictionary from the result.  Any help or advice is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're really quite close.

Instead of this for each RDD:

```
fooGroupRdd = parseFooRdd.map(lambda n: ((n[1], n[3]),\
    n[2])).groupByKey().map(lambda x: {x[0]: list(x[1])})
```

Do this:

```
fooGroupRdd = parseFooRdd.map(lambda n: ((n[1], n[3]),\
    n[2])).groupByKey().map(lambda x: [(x[0]), list(x[1])])
```

That way you can actually access the keys with the rdd.keys() method and create a `bar_keys` list.

```
bar_keys = barGroupRdd.keys().collect()
```

Then you can do exactly what you said. Filter the rows in fooGroupRdd that have a key in bar_keys.

```
dict(fooGroupRdd.filter(lambda x: x[0] not in bar_keys)\
    .map(lambda x: [x[0], x[1]]).collect())
```

The final result looks like this:

```
{('111', 'search'): ['www.google.com', 'www.bing.com', 'www.yahoo.com'],
 ('333', 'news'): ['www.reddit.com', 'www.aol.com', 'www.nytimes.com']}
```

Hope that helps.

Per you comment, I too wondered if this is the most efficient method. Looking into the class methods for RDD you will find `collectAsMap()` which works like collect, but returns a dictionary instead of a list. However, upon investigation of the source code the method simply does exactly what I did, so it would seem this is the best option.

Comment: Thank you, that did it!  Feels like there's so many spark functions in the API that are new to me, I hope this is the most efficient solution.  That first replacement really helped me out, again, much appreciated.